# Sums as rational vector dot products with a basis constants vector

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have series of values which, by visual inspection, appear to be sums of certain constants, not divisible by each other, with rational weights. I want to convert these sums to vectors of weights for a specific basis vector.

I have an initial solution based on `FindInstance`, which works reasonably but I think is not necessarily elegant:

```
ClearAll[splitSumCoefficients];
splitSumCoefficients[sum_, basis_] := 
  With[{cvals = c /@ basis}, 
   cvals/d /. # & /@ 
    FindInstance[
     d sum == basis.cvals && d != 0, {Sequence @@ cvals, d}, 
     Integers]];
```

It works fine for a case where vector values could actually be extracted using expression rewriting:

```
# -> splitSumCoefficients[#, {1, 1/E, E}] & /@ 
 Table[TrigExpand@
   SeriesCoefficient[
    Sin[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] Sinh[Sqrt[1 - x^2]]/(x + 1),
    {x, 0, n}], {n, 0, 5}]
```

> $$\begin{array}{c}
>  \frac{e}{2}-\frac{1}{2 e}\to
>    \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & -\frac{1}{2} &
>    \frac{1}{2} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  1+\frac{1}{2
>    e}-\frac{e}{2}\to \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & \frac{1}{2} &
>    -\frac{1}{2} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  -\frac{1}{2 e}\to \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \frac{1}{2 e}-\frac{1}{6}\to
>    \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  -\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{2} &
>    0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \frac{e}{16}-\frac{7}{16
>    e}\to \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & -\frac{7}{16} &
>    \frac{1}{16} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \frac{1}{120}+\frac{7}{16
>    e}-\frac{e}{16}\to \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \frac{1}{120} & \frac{7}{16}
>    & -\frac{1}{16} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}$$

It also works in a case where expression rewriting would already be a little more tricky:

```
# -> splitSumCoefficients[#, {1, Sinh[1], Cosh[1]}] & /@ 
   Table[SeriesCoefficient[
     Sin[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] Sinh[Sqrt[1 - x^2]]/(x + 1),
     {x, 0, n}], {n, 0, 5}]
```

> $$\begin{array}{c}
>  \sinh (1)\to \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  1-\sinh (1)\to \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & -1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \frac{1}{2} (\sinh (1)-\cosh
>    (1))\to \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & \frac{1}{2} &
>    -\frac{1}{2} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \frac{1}{6} (-1-3 \sinh (1)+3
>    \cosh (1))\to \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  -\frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{2} &
>    \frac{1}{2} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \frac{\sinh (1)}{2}-\frac{3
>    \cosh (1)}{8}\to \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & \frac{1}{2} &
>    -\frac{3}{8} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \frac{1}{120} (1-60 \sinh
>    (1)+45 \cosh (1))\to \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \frac{1}{120} & -\frac{1}{2}
>    & \frac{3}{8} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}$$

(This code can also convert above expressions between $1/sinh/cosh$ and $1/\frac{1}{e}/e$ basis automatically.)

Would there be a more practical solution than `FindInstance` for this problem?

**EDIT**:

A failing example:

```
splitSumCoefficients[#, {1, Sinh[1], Cosh[1]}] &@
 SeriesCoefficient[
  Sin[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] Sinh[Sqrt[1 - x^2]]/(x + 1), {x, 0, 143}]
```

> {}

(That is, no solutions from `FindInstance`.)

Comment: If your solution works for the cases you are interested in, then I can hardly think of a more **practical** solution :P Can you describe the improvements you seek?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I just now remembered what was the alternative, and why it doesn't seem to work for me. `FindIntegerNullVector` does work for small inputs, but fails for bigger ones as it seems to be essentially numerical method. A working example: `-Rest@#/First@# &@
 FindIntegerNullVector[{1/6227020800 + 27007/(92160 E) - (731 E)/
    18432, 1, 1/E, E}]` ... `(* {1/6227020800, 27007/92160, -(731/18432)} *)`

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer And my primary improvement in mind was elegance, or a particularly suitable algorithm for the task. I suspect `FindInstance` might also fail for some inputs!

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be of any use for your problem, but I have old code doing purely structural decomposition: `decomposeInternal = 
 GroupBy[Replace[
    Factor@Replace[
      Expand@#, {sum_Plus :> List @@ sum, 
       expr_ :> {expr}}], {(c : _Integer | _Rational | _Real) x_. :>
{c, x}, Complex[re_, im_] x_. :> Sequence[{re, x}, {im, I x}], 
     x_ :> {1, x}}, {1}], Last -> First, Total] &; 
decompose@l_List := {Values@#, Keys@First[#, <||>]} &@
  KeyUnion[decomposeInternal /@ l, 0 &]; 
decompose@expr_ := {Values@#, Keys@#} &@decomposeInternal@expr;`

Comment: Sorrfy, I didn't pay attention to the comments. You already knew about `FindIntegerNullVector`. My guess is it failed because the `Automatic` precision is too low.

Answer (score 5):

Could use [`FindIntegerNullVector`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIntegerNullVector.html).

```
s143 = SeriesCoefficient[
   Sin[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] Sinh[Sqrt[1 - x^2]]/(x + 1), {x, 0, 143}];
ff = FindIntegerNullVector[{1, Sinh[1], Cosh[1], s143}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 2000]

(* Out[141]= {1, \
3961260330770617476883241243800272591914813378841561500324133049366105\
0123701401772607848046869189487230434065769624598074056818708818344785\
0696665716427876426887640556807563267222769242157291176636056668271262\
5711003773130484745502258300781250000, \
-301687271813430245298615167128172580774085014946504395637814915763577\
7158504130808243502776912161388156812463524288595215733594917752859937\
3098739537990205122300228063774095483218191584013468406883227014757659\
90607108694209686634044834136962890625, \
3854370717180072770521565736493325081944432179154696438432688127620284\
5420193798918144180166658987031965483631719296696351202501036957071818\
6035253548159443361661549763406518875415055453101304885936693315514033\
76640000000000000000000000000000000000} *)
```

It is straightforward to check that this is the correct result. The desired form is simply `-Most[ff]/Last[ff]`.

Comment: Is `s18` supposed to be `s143` (or vice versa)?  And I think you want a minus sign on `s18`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes...I'll fix the `s18` (a holdover from initial experiments). A minus sign can of course be used, or not, so long as one keeps track. I'll fix that too.

Answer (score 3):

This is really an extended comment to @DanielLichtblau's answer, touching the subject of `WorkingPrecision`. I arrived at this completely separately...

Essentially the improvement here is calculating necessary `$MaxExtraPrecision` on basis of input:

```
ClearAll[splitSumCoefficients];
splitSumCoefficients[sum_, basis_] := 
  Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = (Length[basis] + 1) Ceiling[
       Length[basis] + 
        Log10[Max[1, #] &@
           Max@Cases[Expand@Simplify@sum, 
             x_Integer | x_Rational :> 
              Max[Abs@Numerator@x, Denominator@x], Infinity]/
          Min@Abs@basis]]}, 
   Quiet@FindIntegerNullVector[
      Append[-basis, 
       sum]] /. {_FindIntegerNullVector -> {},
                 {most__: 1, last_} :> {{most}/last}}];
```

(Returning `{}` on failure, and handling special cases gracefully like one -element `basis` and no-integer/rational `sum` too.)

Testing it:

```
FullSimplify[# == {1, Sinh[1], Cosh[1]}.First@
      splitSumCoefficients[#, {1, Sinh[1], Cosh[1]}]] &@
 SeriesCoefficient[
  Sin[x] + Sqrt[1 - x^2] Sinh[Sqrt[1 - x^2]]/(x + 1), {x, 0, 143}]
```

> True

Examples of use:

```
splitSumCoefficients[5/3, {1}]
```

> {{5/3}}

```
splitSumCoefficients[1 + 5 E, {1, E}]
```

> {{1, 5}}

```
splitSumCoefficients[E, {1, Sqrt[2]}]
```

> {}

```
splitSumCoefficients[E, {Sinh[1], Cosh[1]}]
```

> {{1, 1}}

($e=\sinh (1)+\cosh (1)$)

Comment: I like it (and upvoted of course). But the general rule for using PSLQ-type methods is that the internal precision required is heavily dependent on output integer sizes. In the common case where one is dealing with algebraic numbers, this is directly related to degree and height of (expected) algebraic relations. For polynomial factorization the degree and height of input give bounds on those output parameters.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yeah, my extra precision calculations are definitely quite ad hoc, but seem to work in this case where integers in input and output are... well, for my original case, essentially identical.

Comment: ... and my basis constants don't have multiplicative relations between each other.

Comment: You do have `c^2-s^2-1` as an algebraic relation. I do not knwo if that helps for getting a bound on needed precision though. I guess it depends on how much you know about where the constant you want to match came from.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau In this case, sizes of integers in the relation should be reasonably well known - they could really be extracted using rewriting after `FullSimplify`. `FindIntegerNullVector` is tricky, though - 56 digits of extra precision is needed in order it to get certain that there is no integer relation with `FindIntegerNullVector[{1, Pi^2, E, Sin[1]}]`!

Comment: I saw a recent paper that suggests somewhat more than twice the output size is in general required for working precision. There might also have been a scale factor to account for the size of the basis. I simply cannot recall the reference though (short term memory is...what was I writing?)

Comment: Found it! [The PSLQ algorithm for empirical data](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/0000-000-00/S0025-5718-2018-03356-7/home.html)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Arxiv link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.05037

Comment: Excellent. Apologies if I completely messed up what they actually show.