# FindInstance fails to find integer solutions to glaringly obvious problems

Tags: equation-solving

This is a continuation question to [Sums as rational vector dot products with a basis constants vector](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179886/sums-as-rational-vector-dot-products-with-a-basis-constants-vector).

Consider the following `FindInstance` query. Looks easy, doesn't it?

```
FindInstance[(x + y Sinh[1] + z Cosh[1])/d ==
  (1 + Sinh[1] + Cosh[1])/2 && d > 0, {x, y, z, d}, Integers]
```

> FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist.

So, no. Many of queries of the same form (varying expected `x`, `y`, `z` and `d`) succeed trivially, while others fail mysteriously. What gives?

`TrigExpand` resolves the problem for these specific constants (`Sinh[1]` and `Cosh[1]`), but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a general solution to the problem of reliable extraction of multipliers to non-rational constants.

**EDIT**:

It is not that this specific case would be hard to work out by finding a suitable method. I'd naively expect that any integer combination of `x`, `y`, `z` and (non-zero) `d` should be trivially recoverable for any such, even structurally obvious linear combination of basis constants (`1`, `Sinh[1]` and `Cosh[1]`). I would expect this process to have $O(1)$ run time complexity on size of these integers if the form is essentially exactly the same on both sides, and to never fail.

`FindInstance` works fine, after all, with many combinations of above variables even when they're like hundred digits long. What is the technical approach `FindInstance` takes here? What would be a more robust method for these kind of problems?

Comment: maybe `FindInstance[
 Rationalize[
   N[(x + y Sinh[1] + z Cosh[1])/d == (1 + Sinh[1] + Cosh[1])/2]] && 
  d > 0, {x, y, z, d}, Integers]`?

Comment: @kglr That's not a result of practical value to me, though. Also, my root question is... what on Earth is going behind the scenes if `FindInstance` fails to find the symbolic result?

Comment: Funny, `FindInstance[(x + y Sinh[1] + z Cosh[1])/-minusd == (1 + Sinh[1] + Cosh[1])/2 && 
  minusd < 0, {x, y, z, minusd}, Integers]` works…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) works in this case if you require all variables to be positive

```
FindInstance[(x + y Sinh[1] + z Cosh[1])/d == (1 + Sinh[1] + Cosh[1])/
    2 && (And @@ Thread[{x, y, z, d} > 0]), {x, y, z, d}, Integers]

(* {{x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 1, d -> 2}} *)
```

Finding other solutions by brute force

```
max = 10;

Thread[{x, y, z, d} -> #] & /@ (Most /@ 
   Select[Flatten[
     Table[{x, y, z, 
       d, (x + y Sinh[1] + z Cosh[1])/d == (1 + Sinh[1] + Cosh[1])/2 && 
        d > 0}, {x, max}, {y, max}, {z, max}, {d, max}], 3], #[[5]] &])

(* {{x -> 1, y -> 1, z -> 1, d -> 2}, {x -> 2, y -> 2, z -> 2, d -> 4}, {x -> 3, 
  y -> 3, z -> 3, d -> 6}, {x -> 4, y -> 4, z -> 4, d -> 8}, {x -> 5, y -> 5, 
  z -> 5, d -> 10}} *)
```

Generalizing,

```
(x + y Sinh[1] + z Cosh[1])/d == (1 + Sinh[1] + Cosh[1])/2 && 
   d > 0 /. {x -> n, y -> n, z -> n, d -> 2 n} // Simplify[#, n > 0] &

(* True *)
```